# circleci: Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()

Tags: php, php-gd, circleci

This post is meant to help those using CircleCI as current posts on SO just say "recompile with freetype" and don't provide any details for CircleCI.

Our unit tests use PHP GD and the PHP binary on the circleci servers has not been compiled with freetype so we get errors like:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()
```

CircleCI support says they may fix this in the future, but in the meantime we need to recompile PHP with freetype. How can we do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile PHP Error with freetype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751203/compile-php-error-with-freetype)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290958/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imagettftext)

Comment: This post is meant to help those using CircleCI as current posts on SO just say "recompile with freetype" and don't provide any details for CircleCI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following worked for me (using the circleci/php:7.3.6-fpm-stretch-browsers image):

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev

sudo docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2/
```

before installing the gd extension with

```
sudo docker-php-ext-install intl gd
```

the link that led me to the solution:
https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php/ (PHP Core Extensions section)